# How to paste canvas context on to a large plane

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've got a user resizeable window and canvas, I copy the canvas before sizing the canvas, then redraw it back, which works well when the user resizes the window bigger.

```
   imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

   canvasWidth  = winW-20;                      // set new width
   canvasHeight = winH-66;                      // set new height
   canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
   canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);

   ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Making the canvas smaller clips the data, how can I copy the canvas data on to a larger temporary plane for redraw big or small without clipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a secondary canvas element you create dynamically:

```
var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

tempCanvas.width = canvas.width;
tempCanvas.height = canvas.height;

tempCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

... resize

ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Just note that many of these operations will eventually reduce the quality so my recommendation would be that you use an off-screen canvas as above but you keep it at a single size through its life-time and then draw to that instead of the on-screen one, and update the on-screen one after each main operation. If this is practically feasible depends of course on your project.

The other approach is to store all draw operations as (custom) objects or something similar and then redraw the whole canvas in scale after each resize. This allow you to keep the data in vector format and get better quality when rasterized to canvas.